# How to print multiples files in a single control?

Tags: c#, image, text, printing

I have an issue regarding printing from a WF App:

I have this code in a button that would allow me to print:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb_tab3_cliente.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty Textbox!");
            }
            else
            {
                if (try2 == false)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            printer_selection = "fCambio";
                            pnt_file.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
                            pnt_file.Print();
                        }
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            printer_selection = "fCambio2";
                            pnt_file.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                            pnt_file.Print();
                        }
                        if (i==2)
                        {
                            printer_selection = "fCambio3";
                            pnt_file.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                            pnt_file.Print();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can see, I manage my print process using a string called "**printer_selection**".
The button makes the printing to iterate through 3 phases, each one contains a 
different .jpeg file, the first one also contains text within the image that is handled on the printing.

The following is what I have inside the `printPage` event:

```
switch (printer_selection)
            {
                case "fCambio":

                    path = Application.StartupPath;
                    file = @"Resources\formats\fCambio.JPG";
                    full = Path.Combine(path, file);

                    print_management = Image.FromFile(full);

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(print_management, -40, 0);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_numeroParte.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 475, 205);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_nombreModelo.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 250, 205);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_round.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 170, 760);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_card.Text+", "+ tb_tab3_card2.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 210, 380);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_spindle.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 170, 580);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_blister1.Text+", "+ tb_tab3_blister2.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 190, 400);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_tray.Text+", "+ tb_tab3_tray2.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 130, 420);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_cover.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 130, 440);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_master.Text+", "+ tb_tab3_master2.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 135, 460);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_subMaster.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 150, 480);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_filler.Text+", "+tb_tab3_filler2.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 135, 500);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_envelope.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 135, 520);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_donut.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 150, 560);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_sleeve.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 135, 540);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_foam.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 130, 600);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_sticker.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 135, 620);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_hang.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 140, 640);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_film.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 130, 660);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_baseModel.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 160, 680);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_barcode.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 150, 700);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_upc.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 135, 720);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_dummy.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 150, 780);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_cartonLid.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 170, 740);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_plan.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 200, 250);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_pallets.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 300, 260);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_masterTrays.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 560, 260);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(tb_tab3_cliente.Text,
                        new Font("Tahoma", 35, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 565, 420);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                        new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 140, 150);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(dgv_tab2.SelectedCells[0].Value),
                        new Font("Tahoma", 35, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, 120, 170);

                    break;

                case "fCambio2":

                    path = Application.StartupPath;
                    file = @"Resources\formats\fCambio2.JPG";
                    full = Path.Combine(path, file);

                    print_management = Image.FromFile(full);

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(print_management, 0, 0);

                    break;

                case "fCambio3":

                    path = Application.StartupPath;
                    file = @"Resources\formats\fCambio3.JPG";
                    full = Path.Combine(path, file);

                    print_management = Image.FromFile(full);

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(print_management, 0, 0);

                    break;               
            }
```

This works correctly, however, the printing is done like this:

Print -> STOP -> Print -> STOP -> Print -> STOP

while the desired is:

Print -> Print -> Print

I know that what I did inside the `printPage` event wont allow me to make an speed up
on my printing process, however I would like to know how to do the multiple 
print process in a single event. 
(In this case print an image file with text above it, and other 2 different images)

Is it possible without third party plugins?
If it is, then, how?

Comment: This code can only ever print one page at a time.  You have to set e.HasMorePages = true to get more than one.  That requires you to keep track of the page number so you know what to print and when to stop.  Add a PageNumber field to your class.  Set it to 0 in a BeginPrint event handler.  Increment it in the PrintPage event handler.  Look at the MSDN article for HasMorePages if you are still confused.

Comment: Thank you, I will check if that helps me and comeback to tell you the results :)

Comment: You don't have to tell me, just post an answer if you want to keep your question.